# Content page not able to access controls after changing the name of the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a web application project in VS2013 with a `Master Page` and some content pages. My master page header is:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MyProject.MasterPage" %>
```

I then right click on the Master Page in the solution explorer and select "Add Content Page". This produces a content page like the following for me:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProject.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

What I do then is right click this "WebForm1" in the solution explorer and change the name to "Login"

This changes the header in the content page to:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyProject.WebForm1" %>
```

Looks fine except it still says `Inherits="MyProject.WebForm1"` despite that no longer being the name of the content page.

So I figure, "OK I can just change `Inherits="MyProject.WebForm1"` to `Inherits="MyProject.Login"`. Big mistake, because now I cannot reference any of the controls like TextBox, Label, etc. in my code behind file. I get a list of errors all along the lines of:

`The name 'controlname' does not exist in the current context`

So it looks like my page can no longer find the class for the controls correctly.

I tried deleting `Login.aspx.designer.cs` and then recreating it by going to `Project -> Convert to web application` but that did not work.

So long story short, my code works fine if I use the `Inherits="MyProject.WebForm1"` despite my page now being called `Login`. I also tried this with all my other pages and it is the same story.

Is this some kind of bug? Or is my method of adding content pages the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely in your code behind you have this:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class WebForm1
```

This is what your page inherits in terms of the web site prokject, and that is what should be in the "Inhertis" attribute. Note that full class name, including namespace, is expected there.

So if you want to rename your page file - make sure you rename the class as well. Visual Studio does not do this automatically.